# NoSuchMethodError when using gradle + ProGuard

Tags: java, gradle, proguard

I'm trying to create ProGuard task for Gradle, but even example task for guard failed with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.getLogging()Lorg/gradle/logging/LoggingManagerInternal`, here is my gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir dirs: 'proguard'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':proguard:'
    }

}

subprojects{
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    tasks.withType(Compile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
sourceCompability = 1.7

dependencies{
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}


}

project(':csl'){
version = "0.1"

dependencies{
    runtime 'com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3'
    runtime group: 'com.jgoodies', name: 'jgoodies-common', version: '1.7.0'
    runtime group: 'com.jgoodies', name: 'jgoodies-forms', version: '1.7.2'
    runtime group: 'com.esotericsoftware', name: 'kryonet', version: '2.22.0-RC1'
    runtime group: 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo', name: 'kryo', version: '2.24.0'
    runtime group: 'org.apache.directory.studio', name: 'org.apache.commons.io', version: '2.4'

}


task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    injars         'build/libs/csl.jar'
    outjars        'build/libs/csl-obf.jar'
//        libraryjars    "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
//        keep 'class org.gradle.** { *; }'
//        printmapping   'csl.map'
//        overloadaggressively
//        repackageclasses ''
//        allowaccessmodification
//
//        keep 'public class mypackage.csl.Main {  \
//    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);  \
//  }'
}

}
```

Commented section not affect on result. In ./proguard there is only proguard.jar 
Or maybe Intellij IDEA has integration with gradle and proguard? The only information I found is about Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading ProGuard from 4.1 to 5.1.
Upgrading gradle from 1.9 to 2.2.1 solved it for me.
Best regards
Christian Teister